# how to get the number of months and exceed days

Tags: asp.net

here is my sample is this correct?

number of months=nms
days=30 days only

sample: nms=30 days count from the date hired

is this correct?

Comment: Can't tell what's the outcome *supposed* to be, so it's hard to tell if it matches an unknown goal. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Which *programming language* are you using in your ASP.NET project? This VB, C#, JavaScript or other?

Comment: It looks correct to me! But then again, a sample of a banana would be correct as well without getting a better idea as to what you are doing.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're trying to do. Showing us a (small!) bit of the code you already have should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get exact month between two date. You have to get difference of them. You can use [DateDiff function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in Dot Net.